# How to redicect url using htaccess in php

Tags: .htaccess, url

I want to redirecy this 
from `www.example.com/babycare/general_help/category.php?id=12`
to

```
www.example.com/article/category/12`
```

where id can be dynamic and change from 1 to 100

here is my htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
IndexIgnore *
```

//this is not working

```
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/general_help/cetegory\.php\?id=([^\s]+)       [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /article/category/%1? [L,R]
```

//this is working

Redirect 301 /babycare/general_help /article

```
Redirect 301 /babycare/general_help /article
Redirect 301 /babycare/aboutus.php /about
Redirect 301 /babycare/contactus.php /contact
Redirect 301 /babycare/login.php /login
Redirect 301 /babycare/pass.php /pass
Redirect 301 /babycare/registrationform.php /registrationform
Redirect 301 /babycare/termsandconditions.php /termsandconditions
Redirect 301 /babycare/disclaimer.php /disclaimer
Redirect 301 /babycare/your_privacy.php /your_privacy
Redirect 301 /babycare/faq.php /faq
Redirect 301 /babycare/useful-links.php /useful-links
Redirect 301 /babycare/faq.php /faq
Redirect 301 /babycare/whyusethisservice.php /how_can_help
Redirect 301 /babycare/sitemap.php /sitemap
Redirect 301 /babycare/guarantee.php /satisfaction
```

//this static pages

```
Redirect 301 /babycare/consultation.php /consultation/first_time
Redirect 301 /babycare/phone_package_detail.php    /consultation/support_options
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/testimonials\.php\?id=7  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /testimonial/cat/5? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/testimonials\.php\?id=6  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /testimonial/cat/4? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/testimonials\.php\?id=5  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /testimonial/cat/3? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/testimonials\.php\?id=1  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /testimonial/cat/1? [L,R]
```

//this is working fine

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/testimonials\.php\?id=3  [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /testimonial/cat/2? [L,R]

    Redirect 301 /testimonials.php /testimonial
```

Comment: But i want to redirect from ww.example.com/babycare/general_help to  www.example.com/article it confulict the above rule

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/article/category/([0-9]+)$ /babycare/general_help/category.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? You didn't just copy paste that line did you? Did you try to tweak for your requirements.....?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/category/([^/]*)$ /babycare/general_help/category.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It will give you the URL: `www.example.com/article/category/12`

Answer (score 0):

i got the error this is now working for me

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/general_help/category\.php\?id=([0-9]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /article/category/%1? [L,R]
```

this redirect me from `www.example.com/babycare/general_help/category.php?id=12` to `www.example.com/article/category/12`

Comment: But i want to redirect this and it conflict     from www.example.com/babycare/general_help to www.example.com/article can anyone tell me what is the probleam